# Showing All Messages clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_ConfirmCode.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_DashBoard1.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_SeniorCitizen.o
duplicate symbol _itemDisplayArray in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_DashBoard1.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_SelectOptionsScreenViewController.o
duplicate symbol _customTablePopup in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_DashBoard1.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_SelectOptionsScreenViewController.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_SelectOptionsScreenViewController.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iToast.o
duplicate symbol _itemDisplayArray in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_DashBoard1.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_EmergencyScreen.o
duplicate symbol _customTablePopup in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_DashBoard1.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_EmergencyScreen.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_EmergencyScreen.o
duplicate symbol _itemDisplayArray in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_DashBoard1.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QnCScreen.o
duplicate symbol _customTablePopup in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_DashBoard1.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QnCScreen.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QnCScreen.o
duplicate symbol _searchString in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_EmergencyScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QnCScreen.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_iSpyDataUpload.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotNotifications.o
duplicate symbol _simulateLatency in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QnCScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ISpyReportScreen.o
duplicate symbol _areaArray in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QnCScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ISpyReportScreen.o
duplicate symbol _countryObjects in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QnCScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ISpyReportScreen.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ISpyReportScreen.o
duplicate symbol _searchString in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_EmergencyScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ISpyReportScreen.o
duplicate symbol _simulateLatency in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QnCScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Agent.o
duplicate symbol _itemDisplayArray in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_DashBoard1.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Agent.o
duplicate symbol _areaArray in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QnCScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Agent.o
duplicate symbol _countryObjects in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/QnCScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Agent.o
duplicate symbol _customTablePopup in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_DashBoard1.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Agent.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Agent.o
duplicate symbol _searchString in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_EmergencyScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Agent.o
duplicate symbol _webData in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_Service.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Agent.o
duplicate symbol _itemDisplayArray in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_DashBoard1.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RegistrationScreen.o
duplicate symbol _pickerViewPopup in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SETUViewController.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RegistrationScreen.o
duplicate symbol _customTablePopup in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_DashBoard1.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RegistrationScreen.o
duplicate symbol _arBloodGroup in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Agent.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RegistrationScreen.o
duplicate symbol _arSelectPhoto in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Agent.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RegistrationScreen.o
duplicate symbol _keyboardIsShown in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Agent.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RegistrationScreen.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RegistrationScreen.o
duplicate symbol _imageData in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Agent.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RegistrationScreen.o
duplicate symbol _stBase64 in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Agent.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RegistrationScreen.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DistressScreen.o
duplicate symbol _serachArray in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_EmergencyScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ImportantContactScreen.o
duplicate symbol _contactView in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_EmergencyScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ImportantContactScreen.o
duplicate symbol _isSearch in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_EmergencyScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ImportantContactScreen.o
duplicate symbol _serachArray in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_EmergencyScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ISpyScreen.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ISpyScreen.o
duplicate symbol _isSearch in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_EmergencyScreen.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ISpyScreen.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MCR.o
duplicate symbol _iToastDuration in:
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Setu_RajkotInitiatives.o
    /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Setu-cegmhpowowqoiffwcwdbpukflsen/Build/Intermediates/Setu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SETU.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SMSScreen.o
ld: 47 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Removing  `-ObjC` from Other Linker Flags...

Comment: i removed it then also gives error

Comment: Set Enable bitcode to NO

Comment: make sure you have imported .m file by mistake.

Comment: i have checked all files there is no any .m imported file

Answer (score 2):

Set the `No Common Blocks` to `No` under the **Apple LLVM 8.0 — Code Generation** in target settings.

[image]